# Pyserial install for Python 3.X (64bit windows)

Tags: pyserial

[Link to install instructions was reviewed.](http://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyserial.html#requirements)

Attempt to install via pip failed:

> C:\Users\User>python
>   Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > pip install pyserial
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           pip install pyserial
> > >                     ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Not sure why there is an error (perhaps this mode only work with LINUX / OSX?).  Very curious.

Fairly certain from other postings that Win-32 bit pyserial installer will not work on Win64.  Ideally, someone who has successfully installed pyserial on Win64 can weigh in and provide link / CLI install instructions.  Spent hours Googling, but have not resolved this install.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing PySerial from the command line in Windows. Just make sure 'pip' is in your PATH.

```
C:\Users\User>pip install pyserial
```

By the way, newer versions of PySerial have some bugs that might affect you on Windows (they did to me). If that happens simply install an earlier version of PySerial. I found that for me 2.7 works just fine.

```
C:\Users\User>pip install pyserial=2.7 -I
```

The flag -I tells pip to ignore other versions and installs (or reinstalls) the defined one.

Comment: Seriously, this helped me. I have Win10 64 version and no guide or troubleshooting in google search solved the problem. But running the command line as administrator and using the first code did the trick!

Comment: It is needed to add a = more in the command, that is to say, pip install pyserial==3.5 -I

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to how many readers have successfully used the install process below. If your are successful please INDICATE by voting-up this response.  PLEASE do not vote-up if you were not successful with the install procedure.

1) Downloaded and unzipped (WinRAR):   [pyserial3.0.1.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyserial/pyserial-3.0.1.tar.gz#md5=c8521e49f8852196aac39431e0901703) to C:\Apps\pyserial

2) At DOS CLI: cd C:\Apps\pyserial

3) At DOS CLI: python setup.py install

> > C:\Users\User>cd \Apps\pyserial
>
> C:\Apps\pyserial>python setup.py install
>
> running install running bdist_egg running egg_info writing top-level
>   names to pyserial.egg-info\top_level.txt writing dependency_links to
>   pyserial.egg-info\dependency_links.txt writing
>   pyserial.egg-info\PKG-INFO reading manifest file
>   'pyserial.egg-info\SOURCES.txt' reading manifest template
>   'MANIFEST.in' writing manifest file 'pyserial.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>   installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg running
>   install_lib running build_py creating build creating build\lib
>   creating build\lib\serial copying serial\aio.py -> build\lib\serial
>   copying serial\rfc2217.py -> build\lib\serial copying serial\rs485.py
>   -> build\lib\serial copying serial\serialcli.py -> build\lib\serial copying serial\serialjava.py -> build\lib\serial copying
>   serial\serialposix.py -> build\lib\serial copying serial\serialutil.py
>   -> build\lib\serial copying serial\serialwin32.py -> build\lib\serial copying serial\win32.py -> build\lib\serial copying serial__init__.py
>   -> build\lib\serial creating build\lib\serial\tools copying serial\tools\hexlify_codec.py -> build\lib\serial\tools copying
>   serial\tools\list_ports.py -> build\lib\serial\tools copying
>   serial\tools\list_ports_common.py -> build\lib\serial\tools copying
>   serial\tools\list_ports_linux.py -> build\lib\serial\tools copying
>   serial\tools\list_ports_osx.py -> build\lib\serial\tools copying
>   serial\tools\list_ports_posix.py -> build\lib\serial\tools copying
>   serial\tools\list_ports_windows.py -> build\lib\serial\tools copying
>   serial\tools\miniterm.py -> build\lib\serial\tools copying
>   serial\tools__init__.py -> build\lib\serial\tools creating
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler copying serial\urlhandler\protocol_alt.py
>   -> build\lib\serial\urlhandler copying serial\urlhandler\protocol_hwgrep.py -> build\lib\serial\urlhandler
>   copying serial\urlhandler\protocol_loop.py ->
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler copying
>   serial\urlhandler\protocol_rfc2217.py -> build\lib\serial\urlhandler
>   copying serial\urlhandler\protocol_socket.py ->
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler copying serial\urlhandler\protocol_spy.py
>   -> build\lib\serial\urlhandler copying serial\urlhandler__init__.py -> build\lib\serial\urlhandler creating build\lib\serial\threaded copying serial\threaded__init__.py -> build\lib\serial\threaded
>   creating build\bdist.win-amd64 creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
>   creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial copying
>   build\lib\serial\aio.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial copying
>   build\lib\serial\rfc2217.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial
>   copying build\lib\serial\rs485.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial
>   copying build\lib\serial\serialcli.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial copying
>   build\lib\serial\serialjava.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial
>   copying build\lib\serial\serialposix.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial copying
>   build\lib\serial\serialutil.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial
>   copying build\lib\serial\serialwin32.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial creating
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\threaded copying
>   build\lib\serial\threaded__init__.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\threaded creating
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools\hexlify_codec.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools\list_ports.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools\list_ports_common.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools\list_ports_linux.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools\list_ports_osx.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools\list_ports_posix.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools\list_ports_windows.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools\miniterm.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools copying
>   build\lib\serial\tools__init__.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools creating
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler copying
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler\protocol_alt.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler copying
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler\protocol_hwgrep.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler copying
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler\protocol_loop.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler copying
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler\protocol_rfc2217.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler copying
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler\protocol_socket.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler copying
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler\protocol_spy.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler copying
>   build\lib\serial\urlhandler__init__.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler copying
>   build\lib\serial\win32.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial copying
>   build\lib\serial__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial
>   byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\aio.py to
>   aio.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\rfc2217.py to rfc2217.cpython-35.pyc
>   byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\rs485.py to
>   rs485.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\serialcli.py to
>   serialcli.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\serialjava.py to
>   serialjava.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\serialposix.py to
>   serialposix.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\serialutil.py to
>   serialutil.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\serialwin32.py to
>   serialwin32.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\threaded__init__.py to
>   **init**.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools\hexlify_codec.py to
>   hexlify_codec.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools\list_ports.py to
>   list_ports.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools\list_ports_common.py to
>   list_ports_common.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools\list_ports_linux.py to
>   list_ports_linux.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools\list_ports_osx.py to
>   list_ports_osx.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools\list_ports_posix.py to
>   list_ports_posix.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools\list_ports_windows.py to
>   list_ports_windows.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools\miniterm.py to
>   miniterm.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\tools__init__.py to
>   **init**.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler\protocol_alt.py to
>   protocol_alt.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler\protocol_hwgrep.py to
>   protocol_hwgrep.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler\protocol_loop.py to
>   protocol_loop.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler\protocol_rfc2217.py to
>   protocol_rfc2217.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler\protocol_socket.py to
>   protocol_socket.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler\protocol_spy.py to
>   protocol_spy.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\urlhandler__init__.py to
>   **init**.cpython-35.pyc byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial\win32.py to win32.cpython-35.pyc
>   byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\serial__init__.py to
>   **init**.cpython-35.pyc creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO installing scripts to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts
>   running install_scripts running build_scripts creating
>   build\scripts-3.5 copying and adjusting serial\tools\miniterm.py ->
>   build\scripts-3.5 creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts
>   copying build\scripts-3.5\miniterm.py ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO\scripts copying
>   pyserial.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
>   copying pyserial.egg-info\SOURCES.txt ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO copying
>   pyserial.egg-info\dependency_links.txt ->
>   build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO copying
>   pyserial.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
>   zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents... creating dist
>   creating 'dist\pyserial-3.0.1-py3.5.egg' and adding
>   'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg'
>   (and everything under it) Processing pyserial-3.0.1-py3.5.egg Copying
>   pyserial-3.0.1-py3.5.egg to
>   c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages
>   Adding pyserial 3.0.1 to easy-install.pth file Installing miniterm.py
>   script to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts
>
> Installed
>   c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pyserial-3.0.1-py3.5.egg
>   Processing dependencies for pyserial==3.0.1 Finished processing
>   dependencies for pyserial==3.0.